# Accessing PHP file through HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, wampserver

I am working on my website which having different tabs (home, contact, etc.). Now in one of these tabs I'm using a login form, in this form I'm just validating one fixed user (**Not Using database**), this will understand from `verification.php` code.

Below is part of `.html` file code that calling `verification.php` file

```
<div id="loginn" class="loginForm">
  <form action="verfication.php" method="post">
    <div class="ll">
      <img src="image/avatar2.png">
    </div>
    <label for="name"><b>Username</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="uname" required><br>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br>
    <input type="password" name="psw" required><br>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Below is my `verification.php` file, which is saved by me in `www` directory, where all the html, css, js files are stored

```
<!DOCTTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['uname']) and isset($_POST['psw']))
  {
    $name=$_POST['uname'];
    $pass=$_POST['psw'];

    if ( $name == "rrrr"  and  $pass="ravina@6543" )
    {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('veri').style.display="block";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('loginn').style.display="none";</script>
    <?php}
  }
?>           
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is, when I click on the login button, there is nothing happening on the html part. I mean, my PHP file is not getting access from my HTML part, so please can anyone help me to solve these problem?

Comment: There is nothing on page `verification.php` to show. Add some data on this file when verified email & password.

Comment: I am changing my div display to "block" to replace new div on that page. Thank you

Comment: The `verification.php` is separate file as you wrote above, so javascript will not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an error in the syntax: first of all there is an additional "T" in the `<!DOCTTYPE html>` and secondly there's a curly bracket after you started the php script: `<?php}`, just adding a space will fix your problem.

There's also a spelling mistake in your html code regarding the name of the php file `verification.php`.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
       if(isset($_POST['uname']) and isset($_POST['psw']))
       {
           $name=$_POST['uname'];
           $pass=$_POST['psw'];

           if ( $name == "rrrr"  and  $pass="ravina@6543" )
           {
       ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('veri').style.display="block";</script>
              <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('loginn').style.display="none";</script>
         <?php }
         }
         ?>          

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: sorry but now it giving me error 404 that my verfication.php is not found on server

Comment: can you try hard reloading the html page with `SHIFT + CTRL + R` ?

Comment: in the html script check the spelling of the verification.php file. There's an error in the name.

Comment: because you misspelled the name of the php file in the form action.

Comment: karan Dhir is my php code is right or not because i am not getting proper output.

Comment: technically it's not right as the `document` in the JavaScript code within your PHP file refers to your PHP document. It seems like you want to make changes in the html file. For that either you merge the PHP and the HTML file or use AJAX in your html file to call the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

in your verification.php, you can check success/not with using only `echo`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['uname']) and isset($_POST['psw']))
   {
       $name=$_POST['uname'];
       $pass=$_POST['psw'];

       if ( $name == "rrrr"  and  $pass="ravina@6543" )
       {
          echo "success~~";
       } else {
          echo "failed!!";
       }
   }
?>          

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Now it is giving 404 error that my php file is not on server ?

Comment: is your .html  file in the same directory with the verification.php file?

Comment: yes my all file html,css,js and php is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to use PHP, HTML and javascript. You should start by learning how HTTP works, then HTML, then JavaScript and finally PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should correctly write the name of php file in your html form i.e. verification.php
verification.php file remove one T from DOCTTYPE html and give one space between php and { in ?php{ this line.